# Script raises 'TypeError: Credentials.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'auth_method'

Tags: python, exchangelib

I am writing script to send email messages.

Here is the main file code:

```py
import config
from exchangelib import Credentials, Account, Message, Mailbox
from exchangelib.errors import UnauthorizedError, TransportError

credentials = Credentials(
    username=config.exchange_username,
    password=config.exchange_password,
    auth_method='ntlm',
)
account = Account(
    primary_smtp_address=config.exchange_email,
    credentials=credentials,
    autodiscover=True,
)
```

here is the config file code:

```py
token = "6666666666:GGGGvbe-cHjjDjuUtRggHtGfFFfF"
exchange_username = 'Asdfgh'
exchange_password = 'AkjhHhgHGhV'
exchange_email = 'Asdfgh@example.com'
exchange_server = 'https://some.mail.gov/owa/'
```

I found on the Internet that the error occurs in the `Credentials(username=config.exchange_username, password=config.exchange_password, auth_method='ntlm')` line, since there is no `auth_method` parameter in the Credentials constructor in the exchangelib library. Instead, the `auth_type` parameter is used. Changed, but the error occurs again already with the description of `auth_type`

If I remove `auth_method='ntlm'` from the code, it gives an error "Authorization error on the Exchange server: No compatible auth type was reported by server"

Comment: The error could've been found when searching the issue tracker. [This](https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib/issues/276) issue discusses the error and why it occurs. It seems that it has nothing to do with the code you posted, but instead something with the Exchange server or the credentials you use.

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace. That makes it a lot easier to see where the error comes from.

Answer (score 0):

The `Credentials` class does not accept an `auth_method` argument.

If you want to specify the authentication type for exchangelib to use, create a `Configuration` instance and use the `auth_type` argument:

```py
credentials = Credentials(username="foo", password="bar")
config = Configuration(
    credentials=credentials,
    auth_type=NTLM,
)
account = Account(
    primary_smtp_address="foo@example.com",
    autodiscover=True,
    config=config,
)
```

There are plenty of examples on how to connect to the server at https://ecederstrand.github.io/exchangelib/#setup-and-connecting